# Which clustering technique to use for a temporal dataset?

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-means

I have seen a similar question but thought I'd ask my own to hopefully garner some usefull feedback.

Basically, I have a large temporal dataset, consisting of domestic smart energy meter use collected at 30 minute intervals for three months. I have data for about 120,000 households and I'm looking to apply an appropriate clustering technique to create customer profiles.

I thought about using K means but I understand that it relies on each reading being independent of the previous which in temporal (and energy use) data is not the case. Am I right in this?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and if you need any extra information, please don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [time series clustering](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=time%20series%20clustering). As you already noted, this consists of two steps:

1. Defining an appropriate distance measure between time series, which should take the particular structure of time series (autoregression, seasonality, ...) into account
2. Using one of the many clustering algorithms, possibly adapted specifically to time series

I personally do not like kmeans very much, I'd rather use DBSCAN (you don't have to prespecify the number of clusters or use some additional algorithm to determine the optimal $k$, and DBSCAN can deal with outliers, i.e., data points that do not belong to any cluster), but everyone has their own favorite here.

[Here](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/time-series-clustering-classification) is a discussion of time series clustering in R. [Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320305001305) is a scholarly survey.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, DBSCAN does seem more appropriate as I certainly have many outliers and peculiarities.

Just out of interest, why would you suggest not to use kmeans?

Comment: kmeans will assign *every* data point to a cluster, and outliers will skew clusters. And you need to prespecify the number $k$ of clusters... or use yet another step (a point 3 above) to determine the optimal number of clusters, like a scree plot or a gap statistic.